# Writing data from multiple NSTextView element into a single file

Tags: cocoa, file, nsdata, nstextview

I have a simple application with 4 NSTextView element.
I would like to be able to write a content of these views into a single file. 
What I am doing write know I am getting the NSData out of each of the elements using: `dataFromRange`, then I concatenate the data and write to a file.

There is however a problem. Each set of NSData I get contains a full file structure; e.g. if I use `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` in `dataFromRange`, in the output file I am getting four HTML files from  to .

How can I avoid that? Is there a common solution for different file types.

Comment: why not extract strings from all the four textviews and append them. Only after this convert it to you NSData.

Comment: That would work for plain ext but not for attributed

Comment: Actually I was wrong! It works perfectly for NSAttributedText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompted by Anoop Vaidya's answer I found solution. What I am doing is:
-for my need I need to start with extra text, here "HEADER"

```
[data [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"HEADER"]] mutableCopy];
```

-next I append the NSAttributedText from each NSTextView like that

```
[data insertAttributedString:[textView1 textStorage] atIndex:[data length]];
```

-finally, I write the combined text to a file using format of choice

```
[[data dataFromRange:range documentAttributes:dict error:error] writeToFile:path atomically:true];
```